# Inverse or inverse derivative of $\frac{x}{2}+\tanh(\beta x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Consider $$ f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \tanh (\beta x) \, ,\qquad x\in [-1,1]\, , \, \beta > 0 \, , $$
**Main question:** Is there a closed form/elementary functions form of either $(f^{-1})'$ or $f^{-1}$?

Computing $\frac{1}{f'} = \left(\frac{1}{2} + \beta \, {\rm sech} ^2 (\beta x) \right)^{-1}$ is easy enough, but this is not precisely what I'm looking for.

**If there isn't any closed form,** I will definitely be interested in any function is "like" $f$. for which we *can* compute the inverse derivative. This is obviously softer than the main question.

Comment: $\operatorname{sech}^2$, not $\operatorname{sech}$.  Also, that is a closed form.  What exactly is it that you need that you don't get from that closed form?  Do you want an expression that comes from differentiating an explicit formula for $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Hey @tilper, thanks. Yeah, $1/f'$ is not the inverse derivative. $1/f'(f^{-1}(y))$ is, and  that's what I'm looking for.